# How to cofigure HMR with nuxt 3 + vite on Gitpod web (behind proxy)

Tags: vite, nuxtjs3, gitpod

I'm new to nuxt and having trouble getting HMR websocket connection configured on a nuxt project and running in Gitpod. The project uses nuxt 3 + vite.

After running `yarn dev` the dev server is running on port 3000 and the frontend tries to connect via websocket to the vite dev server running on port `24678`.

Unfortunately the servers are exposed on Gitpod environments via a reverse proxy and on https endpoints. So the internal servers are running on the defined ports and are publicly exposed on different SSL endpoints like `https://3000-CONTAINER_ID.gitpod.io/` and `https://24678-CONTAINER_ID.gitpod.io/`. But the HMR tries to connect by default to `ws://3000-CONTAINER_ID.gitpod.io:24678/_nuxt/`.

I tried to adjust the vite HMR config on nuxt, but I'm out of luck. The closest I came to what I wanted to achieve was this config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ...
    server: {
      hmr: {
        protocol: 'wss',
        clientPort: 443,
      },
      proxy: {
        '/_nuxt': 'http://localhost:24678/_nuxt',
      }
    },
    ...
});
```

With this the websocket URL in the frontend looks right, being: `wss://3000-CONTAINER_ID.gitpod.io/_nuxt/`, but I get an `WebSocket connection to ... failed.` with an `[vite] server connection lost. polling for restart...` resulting in a page reload endless loop.

I prepared a [git repo](https://github.com/davemecha/nuxt-gitpod-test) that could be directly started in [Gitpod](https://gitpod.io/#https://github.com/davemecha/nuxt-gitpod-test).

Any help to create the right setup to automate my dev environment with Gitpod would be awesome.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make this work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. :(